# Removed cluster disk that wouldn't come online, now it wants to be formatted. Can I recover the data?

Tags: windows-server-2008, storage-area-network, failovercluster, fibre-channel, cluster-shared-volumes

I inherited a failover cluster hosting several VMs and some storage volumes. It uses a fibre-channel SAN for storage. I updated firmware on the SAN controllers recently and when it came back up one of the cluster disks wouldn't come back online in cluster manager. I removed the disk and attempted to add it again after repairing it failed. Now it wants me to format the drive before use. As far as the SAN is concerned everything is fine.

Does removing a cluster storage disk cause all formatting of the disk to be lost? Can I recover it somehow?

Used Easeus program suggested, now have new problem: Easeus detects the volume that I lost, but it can't recover it because it doesn't register it as lost. It thinks that partition is there and formatted and fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing a disk from the cluster does not cause any changes to the disk. I suggest using a partition recovery tool like Active@ to see if the partition is still there and easily recoverable.

Comment: That's what I thought. It's probably the other way around, something went wrong with the volume and that's why it wouldn't come online.

Comment: Active@ recovered the volume. Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, shouldn`t be the problem. Just run some recovery tool. I had a good experience with this one:
http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/

Comment: Hey, cool program. New problem: Easeus detects the volume that I lost, but it can't recover it because it doesn't register it as lost. It thinks that partition is there and formatted and fine. This makes me feel better about the odds of recovering the data.